# Set Form Data to XML tags and save

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I need to fill the `contact` tag with posted form data and send it to a web service.
my problem is can't access `contact:firstname` tag.

`print_r($xml->create)` results empty object `SimpleXMLElement Object ( )`

how can i set `$_POST['firstname']` into e.g. `contact:firstname` tag ?

**this is my xml file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<epp xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0">
    <command>
        <create>
            <contact:create xmlns:contact="http://epp.example.com/ns/contact-1.0">
                <contact:postalInfo type="int">
                    <contact:firstname></contact:firstname>
                    <contact:lastname></contact:lastname>
                    <contact:idNumber type="NationalID" cc="XX"></contact:idNumber>
                    <contact:addr>
                        <contact:street></contact:street>
                        <contact:city></contact:city>
                        <contact:sp></contact:sp>
                        <contact:pc></contact:pc>
                        <contact:cc></contact:cc>
                    </contact:addr>
                </contact:postalInfo>
                <contact:voice></contact:voice>
                <contact:fax></contact:fax>
                <contact:email></contact:email>
                <contact:authInfo>
                    <contact:pw></contact:pw>
                </contact:authInfo>
            </contact:create>
        </create>
        <clTRID></clTRID>
    </command>
</epp>
```

**and this is my php code:**

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

/*
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('data.xml');
*/
?>
```

Comment: Look into [DOM documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php).

Comment: @DainisAbols I love you <3